# How to create dynamic JSON in Jmeter?

Tags: csv, groovy, jmeter

I have csv file it looks like:

```
Client_id, uid
1           a
1           b
1           c
2           d
2           e
```

(one client_id can have some uids)

I need to send a request with Jmeter. The request should look like this:

```
{
    "${uida}":["DCC","BALANCE","SECURITY","INET_LIMIT","SHOPPING_PIN"],
    "${uidb}":["DCC","BALANCE","SECURITY","INET_LIMIT","SHOPPING_PIN"],
    "${uidc}":["DCC","BALANCE","SECURITY","INET_LIMIT","SHOPPING_PIN"]
}
```

and client_id must be in header.
**How can I do it?**

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/json.html#_jsonoutput

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a JSON payload from the CSV file:

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler you want to parameterize
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
   import groovy.json.internal.LazyMap

   def lines = new File('test.csv').readLines()
   def uids = lines[1..lines.size() - 1].collect { line -> line[2] }
   def value = ["DCC", "BALANCE", "SECURITY", "INET_LIMIT", "SHOPPING_PIN"]
   def payload = new LazyMap()
   uids.each { uid ->
       payload.put(uid, value)
   }
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString(), '')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```

it will create the body in the required format.

References:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

With regards to the header - you can add it via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), unfortunately your question doesn't have enough information to suggest comprehensive configuration.